# How to create a new "templates" category on Xcode 4 and use my own file templates there?

Tags: ios, templates, xcode4, customization

I would like to start using my own templates for iOS applications. I don't want any significant changes, but simpler things like

- add/remove some boilerplate code
- add some `pragma mark` sections
- hardcode my company's name and some comments for every file
- change the indentation
- etc etc etc

The idea is that we will share these templates when we create apps, but at the same time **we want to keep** the default template files that Xcode 4 already provides. So, in the following screenshot, how can I add a "CompanyName Application" section that contains exactly the same templates (Navigation-based, View-based etc), but with my own changes?

[image: Xcode 4 templates]

I found that I can add a folder under `/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/` or `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/` but I'm a bit confused with what do I need to do exactly. I would really appreciate it if you could help me with that, as I have already messed up my folders twice with no luck. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This blog post by *borealkiss*](http://blog.boreal-kiss.net/2011/03/11/a-minimal-project-template-for-xcode-4/) has detailed instructions. For starters:

> If you add your own templates, the place you should use is under the following path:
>
> ```
> ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/
> ```
>
> The problem is that it is quite hard to create a custom template. 
>   For example, to copy and paste the
>   built-in template to your place will
>   not show up the template on Xcode 4
>   until you manually change its
>   identifier in TemplateInfo.plist.

Comment: Related links: http://snipt.net/yonishin/about-xcode-4-project-template https://github.com/ngs/xctemplates Or at least the only information I could find on the subject.

Comment: And slides from a presentation by Abizer Nasir on the subject: http://lanyrd.com/2011/lidg28/sffpf/

Comment: Hi Hagelin, if you are still interested in the subject see http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/store/xcode4-template-documentation/ I managed to build a complex template (https://github.com/j4n0/xcode4) following his instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this article from Bob McCune "[Creating Custom Xcode 4 File Templates](http://www.bobmccune.com/2012/03/04/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/)" that is exactly what I needed, so I put it here for reference.